# getting error with default examples - imdbpy

Tags: python, imdbpy

Installed imdbpy and tried running the default examples mentioned on -http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/support.html, but I am unable to run them successfully.

Program:

```
# Create the object that will be used to access the IMDb's database.
ia = imdb.IMDb() # by default access the web.

# Search for a movie (get a list of Movie objects).
s_result = ia.search_movie('The Untouchables')

# Print the long imdb canonical title and movieID of the results.
for item in s_result:
   print item['long imdb canonical title'], item.movieID

# Retrieves default information for the first result (a Movie object).
the_unt = s_result[0]
ia.update(the_unt)

# Print some information.
print the_unt['runtime']
print the_unt['rating']
director = the_unt['director'] # get a list of Person objects.

# Get the first item listed as a "goof".
ia.update(the_unt, 'goofs')
print the_unt['goofs'][0]

# The first "trivia" for the first director.
b_depalma = director[0]
ia.update(b_depalma)
print b_depalma['trivia'][0]
```

Error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /Users/karan/PycharmProjects/IMDBParser/extractor/imdbpy_tester.py
Untouchables, The (1987) 0094226
Untouchables (in development), The (????) 1987680
"Untouchables, The" (1959) 0052522
"Untouchables, The" (1993) 0106165
Intouchables, The (2011) 1675434
Untouchables, The (2017) 1877895
Untouchable (I) (2016) 5509634
Untouchable 2, The (2001) (VG) 0287778
"Untouchable" (2015) 4191792
Untouchable, The (1997) (VG) 0287779
Untouchable (2012) 2266916
"Untouchable" (2017) (mini) 5220680
Untouchable (I) (2010) 1590231
Untouchable (III) (2013) 3001590
Untouchables, The (1991) (VG) 0335509
"Frontline" The Untouchables (2013) 2620144
"DVD_TV: Enhanced Version" The Untouchables (2005) 1088289
"Real Story, The" The Untouchables (2009) 2760176
"Harbour Lights" The Untouchables (1999) 0596815
"Bill, The" The Untouchables (2000) 0525783
[u'119']
7.9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/karan/PycharmProjects/IMDBParser/extractor/imdbpy_tester.py", line 27, in <module>
    print the_unt['goofs'][0]
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IMDbPY-5.0-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/imdb/utils.py", line 1469, in __getitem__
    rawData = self.data[key]
KeyError: 'goofs'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I found sth similar posted by another user here - https://bitbucket.org/alberanid/imdbpy/issues/42/examples-not-functional but I do not know how to fix this problem.